# Is there any way I can make deluge to get minimised to tray icon at the topbar when clicked on 'x(close)'?

Tags: system-tray, deluge

I torrent a lot and I just don't want to close deluge even by mistake!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deluge has deamon called
[deluged](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/deluged) [image: Install deluged]
. You can use that so that even after closing the deluged UI (delug-gtk), it will run continuously in the background.

Install it using

```
sudo apt-get install deluged.
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to edit menu, preferences and enable notification icon and also notification indicator if you are in Unity.

Comment: thank you I found it under interface section in preferences. there was a check-box option to minimize to tray on close